# Mongoose - Difference between Error.ValidationError, and Error.ValidatorError

Tags: node.js, mongoose

The question pretty much says it all.

As far as I can tell from the docs, one is for general validation errors (a `required` field not being included, `maxLength` being exceeded, etc.).

And one is given as the `reason` within the other, whenever an error occurs within a custom validator... Is that correct?

If so, which is which? The naming convention used is really confusing here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more research, and investigation. It seems that all validation type errors (which include `Error.CastError` errors) always exist within a, `Error.ValidationError` object. This is the parent object, and itself doesn't really offer much information, other than that validation has failed somewhere along the line.

Within this `Error.ValidationError` object, can be many other error objects. It's these *children* that will be instances of `Error.ValidatorError` (or `Error.CastError`).

A validation error will therefore look something like:

```
// When receiving some error, with the variable name "err".
err instanceof mongoose.Error.ValidationError
// true

console.log(err);
errors: {
  some_doc_field_name: {}     // Possibly an instanceof "Error.ValidatorError"
  another_doc_field_name: {}  // Possibly an instanceof "Error.CastError"
}
```

TL;DR:

- Validat**ion**Error = the parent type of the error.
- Validat**or**Error = one of the potential children types of error it's children can have.